# android firebase phone authentication can we store in the mysql database using firebase for otp

Tags: mysql, firebase, firebase-authentication

how to store phone authentication of firebase using mysql to access data from the mysql data base. can we store the id of the phone authentication in mysqli. if we can then how to store phone authentication  id in the mysql. to access the the db related to phone no.

example
if i am using firebase phone authentication to authenticate the user
but my data is in mysql how to access these date for particular user from the id of phone authentication.
if any have any link please share with me or any idea to access these this please answer.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load data for the current user from a SQL database, you'll want to do something like:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
  String query = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE uid = " + user.getUid();
  ...
}
```

This is for Android. If you're targeting a different platform, see [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed_in_user) in the Firebase docs for that platform.